# VideoDisplay fullscreen

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, blackberry-playbook, qnx

How does one do fullscreen with VideoDisplay?

I am using:

```
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(video.x, video.y, video.width, video.height);
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

But this does not allow me to go back to normal screen, not even i use:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the playbook dev support forums, you do not use StateDisplay in playbook for video maximization because the screen already runs in StageDisplay.FULLSCREEN_INTERACTIVE so it doesn't work - set the video dimensions to the size of the screen. And then back again to reduce.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot test this right now but you have written `stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL` with `==` instead of `=`.

Instead of assigning the value `StageDisplayState.NORMAL` to `stage.displayState` you simply compare the two.

Comment: yeah, == will do a comparison and return a boolean value.

Comment: Still nothing, sorry that was my typo - but, didn't work still on the playbook.

Comment: I don't understand if you are getting to full screen and can't get back or you can't even get to full screen.

Comment: Hi Rob, I can get to fullscreen but not back. Setting the stage to normal does nothing, i expect its because all playbook apps run in fullscreen anyway.